# Cx_freeze ImportError no module named scipy

Tags: python, scipy, cx-freeze

Good day all,

I am having trouble using cx_Freeze on a code I am working on converting to a .exe.

When I run cx_Freeze I get the following ImportError that there no no module named scipy

```
running install
running build
running build_exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 25, in <module>
    executables = executables
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 362, in setup
    distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 539, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 126, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 232, in run
    freezer.Freeze()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 619, in Freeze
    self.finder = self._GetModuleFinder()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 378, in _GetModuleFinder
    finder.IncludePackage(name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 686, in IncludePackage
    module = self._ImportModule(name, deferredImports)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 386, in _ImportModule
    raise ImportError("No module named %r" % name)
ImportError: No module named 'scipy'
```

I can confirm that I have Scipy 0.16 installed on my system which works when I import it into other python code. I am currently running python 3.4 on Windows. The following is my setup.py file for cx_Freeze.

```
import cx_Freeze
import sys
import matplotlib

base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable('fractureGUI.py', base=base, icon='star_square.ico')]

packages = ['tkinter','matplotlib','scipy']

include_files = ['star_square.ico', 'C:\\Python34\\Lib\\site-packages\\scipy']

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = 'FracturePositionMonteCarlo',
    options = {'build_exe': {'packages':packages,
        'include_files':include_files}},
    version = '0.01',
    description = 'Fracture Depth Monte Carlo',
    executables = executables
    )
```

The following is the import section of my main script, fractureGUI.py.

```
import scipy
from random import random

import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib import style
style.use('ggplot')

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog

import sys
import json
```

If anybody has any ideas why cx_Freeze is unable to find scipy please do let me know. I tried to add the filepath to scipy under include_files but it made no difference.

Kind regards,

Jonnyishman

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue. Found the solution here:
https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issues/43/import-errors-when-using-cx_freeze-with

Find the hooks.py file in cx_freeze folder. Change line 548 from finder.IncludePackage("scipy.lib") to finder.IncludePackage("scipy._lib").

Leave the "scipy" entry in packages and delete 'C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\scipy' in include_files.

Comment: Cheers man. I made the change and now it works a treat. You're a star.

Comment: Changing `hooks.py` as suggested here solves the issue, but I don't understand how. Why is this solution working?

Comment: Your solution did not work, It threw an error as no file named sys<for module collections.sys> Line 762 of ..\cx_Freeze\freezer.py

Comment: This solution also addresses the `No module named scipy.spatial.ckdtree` issue, which I was having - even after appying the `setup.py` file fixes [here](https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/issues/233).

Comment: Additionally ... for `cx_freeze` v5.0.2, it's on line 564.

Answer (score 1):

For all the Scipy related issues gets resolved if you include them in the script. It worked for me. Please refer my working script 
(Note: this script doesnot have any UI library like tkinter)

This scripts fetches the data from config file and returns the addition two number which is get written in the file in the working directory.

**FolderStructure**

[image]

**setup.py**

```
import sys
import cx_Freeze
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
from scipy.sparse.csgraph import _validation
import scipy
import matplotlib

'''Include the package for which you are getting error'''
packages = ['matplotlib','scipy']
executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable('main.py', base='Win32GUI')]

'''include the file of the package from python/anaconda installation '''
include_files = ['C:\\ProgramData\\Continuum\\Anaconda\\Lib\\site-packages\\scipy']

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = 'Test1',
    options = {'build_exe': {'packages':packages,
        'include_files':include_files}},
    version = '0.1',
    description = 'Extraction of data',
    executables = executables
    )
```

**main.py**

```
import os, numpy as np
import configparser
from helper_scripts.help1 import Class_A

path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath('__file__')) + '\\'
conf = configparser.ConfigParser()
conf.read(path + 'config.ini')

a = eval(conf.get('inputs','input_1'))
b = eval(conf.get('inputs','input_2'))

obj = Class_A()

res = obj.getData(a,b)

if not os.path.exists(path + 'Result.txt'):
    with open(path + 'Result.txt', 'w', encoding ='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(f'result is : {str(res)}\n')

else:
    with open(path + 'Result.txt', 'a', encoding ='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(f'result is : {str(res)}\n')
```

**Command to generate the exe file**

```
''' make sure  to run the below command from working directory where the setup.py file is present.'''

python setup.py build
```

The build folder gets created with main.exe file all the required binaries files.

*Note: Place the config.ini file in the exe folder so that exe can access the config file and produce the output.*

[image]

Comment: thanks. That really helped me with the pyttsx3 module errors.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I still don't have rep to comment, but for the op having issues with the "No module named scipy.spatial.ckdtree" error, I solved it by simply renaming "cKDTree.cp37-win_amd64" to "ckdtree.cp37-win_amd64" under scipy\spatial folder. I had similar issues with libraries being imported with capital letters here and there.